# Unity + iOS + Xcode woes

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I set up the provisioning profile, the certificate, device identifier, etc and can build my ios project with no errors.

On my iPAD I see an icon with my app name but when I open it, the screen turns white and it does nothing...

The build is working fine on android, which I used to develop it, Unity builds an ios build with no problem, I open that folder as a new xcode project, and can build it then run but it doesn't do anything....xcode says "Running"....

Any idea's??? What a p.i.t.a....I thought I'd be golden after getting it to build...I've uploaded the build to dropbox and try to open on the ipad but it just says "Open with dropbox?" after it zips the folder as I try to download it to the device.....

Comment: Have you verified the log on Xcode console when opening it on iPad?

Comment: What do you see in console when running from Xcode? It should start with _Initialize engine version: 3.5.7f6_ and end with _-> applicationDidBecomeActive()_. If so: Do you see the splash screen then on your iPad? If not: Take a new empty Unity project and try this. I didn't get this Dropbox thing, what do you mean by this?

Comment: There is no splash screen, it just shows white, and the icon for the app on the device doesn't have an image, just a light gray color. When I click build and run I don't get any errors, it says build successful then the gray icon shows on the device and if I kill the program on the device xcode stops logging it and throws an error. Today my boss took the ipad so don't know what the console is saying exactly. Ugh.